# Wi-Fi Wireless Diagnostics -> Sidecar Diagnostics: why not working?

Tags: macos, wifi, ventura

I have discovered the very powerful wireless Diagnostics tools. But, trying to use the Sidecar Diagnostics tool, it always shows empty graphs. How is this tool supposed to work?

Furthermore, do you know an alternative way to collect channel congestion statistics, last panel, since this is not working as expected?

Running macOS Ventura 13.0.

[image: Empty Sidecar Diagnostic screenshot]

Comment: Do you have an iPad sidecar-connected? Can't test but maybe it has nothing to report until there is.

Comment: No, you are probably right. But channel congestion are statistics totally independent of what is connected... At least in principle